# 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Dispose'

Tags: c#

`protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)`

In the line above I am getting an error.

The Error is:

```
windowformapplication.form1.Dispose(bool): not suitable method found to override
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `IDisposable` interface to the form object?

Comment: Which error is it; the one in your title or the one in your question?

Comment: Have you renamed your form after adding it to the solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1)You might have renamed your `class Form` to `class Form1`  without renaming your designer file i.e `Partial class Form.designer.cs` to `Partial class Form1.designer.cs`
2)Your InitializeComponent(); would have deleted or commented in your windowformapplication.form1() constructor.

Or try adding following code in your designer.cs.

```
 /// <summary> 
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Be sure that your Form1.cs extend from Form. Such as **public partial class Form1 : Form{..}**